# Turn a col into rownames in a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dplyr

I have a list of dataframes for which I would like to turn one of their cols into the rownames.
(instead of doing this for every df individually).

Unfortunatly I cant get it to work, maybe someone can help?

```
DF1 <- data.frame(A = c("A", "B", "C"),
                  B = 1:3)
DF2 <- data.frame(A = c("A", "B", "C"),
                  B = 1:3)
TheList <- list(DF1 = DF1,
                DF2 = DF2)
col_to_rownames_andDel <- function(df){
  rownames(df) <- df$A
  df$A <- NULL
}

TheList_namedRows <- map(TheList, col_to_rownames_andDel) #not working and empties the dfs
```

Thanks!

Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the changed dataframe in the last line of the function.

```
col_to_rownames_andDel <- function(df){
   rownames(df) <- df$A
   df$A <- NULL
   return(df)
}

TheList_namedRows <- purrr::map(TheList, col_to_rownames_andDel)
#Using lapply
#TheList_namedRows <- lapply(TheList, col_to_rownames_andDel)

TheList_namedRows
#$DF1
#  B
#A 1
#B 2
#C 3

#$DF2
#  B
#A 1
#B 2
#C 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah well... seems I simply forgot the return argument in the function. 
It might be useful for others so I keep it here.

```
col_to_rownames_andDel <- function(df){
  rownames(df) <- df$A
  df$A <- NULL
  return(df)
}

TheList_namedRows <- map(TheList, col_to_rownames_andDel)
```

Rubber duck debugging at its best.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
map(.x = TheList,
    ~ .x %>%
    column_to_rownames("A"))

$DF1
  B
A 1
B 2
C 3

$DF2
  B
A 1
B 2
C 3
```

Comment: I appreciate that its a dplyr solution but Ronak was faster. Still much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `column_to_rownames` from `tibble`

```
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
map(TheList,  column_to_rownames, "A") 
#$DF1
#  B
#A 1
#B 2
#C 3

#$DF2
#  B
#A 1
#B 2
#C 3
```